# how to call a class's method within his pointer?

Tags: c++, class

I stored a class in a vector (just one for exemple) of pointer and I do not get the syntax to call its method.

I tried something like this : storedclasses[0].itsmethod(); but it returns "error: request for member ‘itsmethod’ in..." (...)

```
class Bulb {
    public:
        class Leaf {
            public:
                void readval() {
                    cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << endl;
                }
            private:
                float a[3]={0.0};
                float b[3]={0.0};
                float c[3]={0.0};
        };
        void createLeaf(){
            Leaf * leaf = new Leaf();
            leaflist.push_back(leaf);
            cout << "It's okay :-)" << endl;
            //what my compiler hates :
            leaflist[1].readval();
        }
    private:
        vector<Leaf*> leaflist;
};

int main(void) {
    Bulb bulb; bulb.createLeaf();
}
```

Comment: With pointers you use `->` to access members.

Comment: Shame on me thank you

Comment: Note: On a modern processor `vector` is at its best when it directly contains objects. objects in a `vector` are contiguous in memory and that makes it ridiculously easy for the CPU to read ahead of the program and have data available when it is needed. With pointers to separate dynamic allocations, the CPU has to hop around through memory gathering all of the scattered objects and never really picks up the kind of speed it can get with continuous longer reads.

Comment: Nice to know thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
leaflist[0]->readval();
```

In C, C++, Java, and most other non-scripting languages, arrays start at 0, not 1, including container classes like vectors, etc. Thus, not 1 like you have, but 0.

And because you're holding pointers, you need to dereference the pointer. leaflist[0] holds a pointer, and then you use -> to dereference it.